# How to fetch list of published webforms from webform module?

Tags: 7, webforms

How can I fetch list of published webforms from webform module?

I want to show all published webforms in dropdown to the user, so user can select one of the available forms.

Cheers
-Zafar

Comment: you can use views, currently dont have enough time to explain, but if u couldn't figure it out, I will explain it to you in an hour

Comment: I need a dropdown with listing published webforms in FORM(hook_form),views would be good idea for only showing/listing webforms seperately.

Comment: I need a query to fetch all published webforms from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7 it would be something like:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array(
  'type' => 'webform',
  'status' => 1,
));
```

Have a look at the docs for [node_load_multiple](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7). You could (and probably should) also use EntityFieldQuery as mentioned in the docs. The given examples assumes that you use the default webform content type.

You could then use the `$nodes` array to build options for a Form API select element:

```
$webforms = array();
foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
  $webforms[$nid] = check_plain($node->title);
}
$form['available_webforms'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Webforms'),
  '#options => $webforms,
);
```